# функция sleep в PHP

Tags: php, sleep

функция sleep в PHP на вертуальном сервере не работает как нужно , ( в PHP онлайн тесте, работает нормально)
задача сделать интервал на кaждое предложение в 3 секунды 
       (

```
   echo '<p>Rong see sõitis tsuhh tsuhh tsuhh,</p>';
   flush();
   sleep(3);
   echo '<p>piilupart oli rongijuht.</p>';
   sleep(3);
   echo '<p>Rattad tegid rat tat taa,</p>';
   sleep(3);
   echo '<p>rat tat taa ja tat tat taa.</p>';
   sleep(3);
   echo '<p>Aga seal rongi peal,</p>';
   sleep(3);
   echo '<p>kas sa tead, kes olid seal?</p>';
   sleep(3);)
```

просто виснет и загружается весь текст, а не выводит , каждое предложение с интервалом в 3 секунды

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3685760

Comment: пробовал,....но увы, буду искать дальше спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохраняете набор предложений в массив, проходите в цикле по массиву, и на каждой итерации делаете сброс буфера и трёхсекундный сон:

```
$words = [
    'Rong see sõitis tsuhh tsuhh tsuhh,',
    'piilupart oli rongijuht.',
    'Rattad tegid rat tat taa,',
    'rat tat taa ja tat tat taa.',
    'Aga seal rongi peal,',
    'kas sa tead, kes olid seal?',
];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo "<p>$word</p>";
    flush();
    sleep(3);
}
```

---

**UPD** Ещё вариант с передачей GET-параметров:

```
$sleep = 3; // Время обновления
$file = 'view.txt';
$words = [
    'Rong see sõitis tsuhh tsuhh tsuhh,',
    'piilupart oli rongijuht.',
    'Rattad tegid rat tat taa,',
    'rat tat taa ja tat tat taa.',
    'Aga seal rongi peal,',
    'kas sa tead, kes olid seal?'
];

$k = isset($_GET['k']) ? (int) abs($_GET['k']) : 0;
$view = file_exists($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : '';

$view .= "<p>$words[$k]</p>";
file_put_contents($file, $view);
empty($words[++$k]) ?: header("Refresh:$sleep; url=?k=$k");

if ($k == count($words)) {
    file_put_contents($file, '');
    $view .= '<a href="?">Refresh</a>';
}

echo $view;
```

Но у этого варианта недостаток в том, что обновлять страницу можно только по ссылке
*(или руками в адресной строке удалять параметры)*

> См. [Демо](http://h66862p8.bget.ru/temporary/index.php) на хостинге

Comment: Спасибо большое, понятно объяснили, держите пожалуйста + в карму )

Comment: @alex но такой метод не везде работает. Если нужно, могу написать более универсальный пример.

Comment: Эдуард, Буду признателен, если покажете ваш вариант, спасибо

Comment: @alex я обновил ответ, но лучше подобные вещи писать на JS. Для просмотра работы скрипта наведите курсор на спойлер в конце моего поста, и перейдите по отобразившейся ссылке.

Comment: Эдуард, большое вам человеческое спасибо, за вашу помощь ))) этот вариант идеален, для меня!